# Can I use Google Earth Server as the base map for openLayers?

Tags: linux, dictionary, openlayers, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to embed a map in my web application and am looking at options to start from scratch.  I have access to a google earth server for thick client google earth.  I do not have the option to use google earth plugin. (clients are using Linux and there is no google earth plugin available on Linux).  Can I use the google Earth server to somehow create a base map or WMS service for use in OpenLayers?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view there is no problem using it as a WMS base layer. Like [this example](http://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/chouse/wms/wms_image_server_google_earth_instructions.html).